# Sequelize – where with count

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm having three models that extend `Sequelize.Model` and have migrations generated. The associations look like this:

**Foo**

```
Foo.belongsToMany(Bar, {
  as: 'bars',
  through: 'FooBar',
  foreignKey: 'foo_id',
});
```

**Bar**

```
Bar.belongsToMany(Foo, {
  as: 'bars',
  through: 'FooBar',
  foreignKey: 'bar_id',
});
```

**FooBar**

```
FooBar.belongsTo(Foo, {
  as: 'foo',
  foreignKey: 'foo_id',
});
FooBar.belongsTo(Bar, {
  as: 'bar',
  foreignKey: 'bar_id',
});
```

I'm trying to query Foo like this:

```
const foos = await Foo.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Bar,
    as: 'bars',
  }],
});
```

The code works as expected and I get the array of `bars` for each of my `foo`.

**How can I now query foos that only have `bars` count that is more than e.g. 2?**

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do this in sequelize.
Two ways you can do it:

- First way: (2 queries)

  - Find all the foo ids that have 2 bars in 1 query (probably raw query)
  - Add those foo ids as a filter in where of your findAll
- Second way: (1 query)

  - Create a sequelize literal of a subquery that returns foo ids that have more than 2 bars and add that literal to `where: { id: <subquery literal> }`

---

Showing Second way:
subquery literal e.g.:

```js
sequelize.literal(`(
SELECT 
  id 
FROM foo 
LEFT JOIN bar ON bar.foo_id = foo.id 
WHERE COUNT(bar.id) > 2 
GROUP BY foo.id
)`)
```

Final findAll:

```js
const foos = await Foo.findAll({
  where: {
    id: sequelize.literal(`...`),
  },
  include: [{
    model: Bar,
    as: 'bars',
  }],
});
```